# Desktop icons rearrange after restart

Tags: macos, desktop

The icons on my desktop (El Capitan) keep rearranging after every restart.
In the same order as well, when I try to rearrange my icons it will let me do so but after a restart the icons revert to the arrangement.
Any ideas on why and how to fix it?

Comment: Possibly the Finder Menu's View/"sort by" option has been set to something other than "none".

Comment: @WayfaringStranger No it is set to none. There isn't any order eg. Kind, Alphabetical, Date Modified, or anything. it just froze my desktop to where I can't permanently move icons on the desktop.

Comment: Try deleting ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState then relaunch the finder. As it's hard to keep the Finder down, it might need a couple of tries, it's not something I've attempted.